# BPF expression to capture only arp-reply packets

Tags: java, packet-capture, arp, bpf, pcap4j

Is there a [BPF](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) expression that would only capture arp-reply packets? Currently, I am using Pcap4J and the following BPF expression:

> arp and dst host *host* and ether dst *mac*

where *host* is the IP address of my device and *mac* is the MAC address of my primary network interface. Unfortunately, when packets are captured, this filter allows ARP broadcast requests to also be captured, so I have to take an extra step to check if the operation field of the ARP header is 2 and not 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

> (arp[6:2] = 2) and dst host host and ether dst mac

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. Can you explain what the `6:2` index is doing?

Comment: The 6 is the offset in ARP header, where the operation field starts. The 2 is the field's length. arp[6:2] returns the operation field's value.