# c/c++ pcap filter expression for ARP reply packets

Tags: c++, c, pcap, libpcap, arp

I am trying to create pcap filter for filtering ARP replies only. In wireshark i use

```
arp.opcode==2
```

and it works perfectly. But when i use it in pcap_compile function, it throws an exception - syntax error. I tried also these variants:

```
arp.opcode = 2
arp.opcode 2
arp opcode 2
arp.reply
arp reply
```

and nothing seems to work. I tried to google it, but no success. Is it even possibly to filter that specific packets?

Comment: Just use either C or C++. Don't tag the post with both. Also add the code without which we can't help.

Comment: pcap filters are not as sophisticated as the expressions Wireshark supports. Documentation at e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter. You might be better off just filtering for arp traffic and then checking for replies in code; otherwise you're going to need to research the arp packet format at the byte level.

Comment: @AlanStokes Yea, i figured. I wanted to make it simpler, but i guess it cant be done. Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this should work, based on the packet structure from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#Packet_structure):

```
arp [6:2] = 2
```

That's also suggested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199540/212870

(It's easier to look up once you figure out the answer, unfortunately.)